Oracle Procedure - Calling Procedures with Procedure records not inserted
I have an Oracle procedure that calls multiple procedures, structured as follows:
Parent Procedure

ChildProc1: Inserts 180 records into TableA
ChildProc2: Inserts 180 more records into TableA
ChildProc3: Inserts all records from TableA into TableB

When I execute the parent procedure, I observe the following:

180 records are inserted into TableA by ChildProc1
180 records are inserted into TableA by ChildProc2
0 records are inserted into TableB by ChildProc3
However, when I check TableA afterward, it contains 0 records.

Interestingly, when I comment out the call to ChildProc3, TableA ends up with 360 records.
I've implemented commits after each insert and after the procedure call. I'm puzzled as to why the records in TableA are disappearing

because you didn't commit them

Please post a reproducible test case.  My guess would be that you've either got an exception handler that is hiding a failure from you or that you're using an autonomous transaction.  But without seeing any code, there are a huge number of possible problems.

If childproc3 either:

explicitly performs a ROLLBACK; or
implicitly performs a ROLLBACK by raising an (uncaught) exception; or
you close the session without COMMITting the transaction.

Then all the changes will be rolled back and all the values inserted by the previous procedures will be rolled back as they are part of the same transaction.

If you have the tables:
CREATE TABLE a(id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
CREATE TABLE b(id NUMBER);

And the procedures:
CREATE PROCEDURE childproc1
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 180 LOOP
    INSERT INTO a (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE childproc2
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 180 LOOP
    INSERT INTO a (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE childproc3(raise_exception BOOLEAN)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO b (id)
  SELECT id FROM a;

  IF raise_exception THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'An Error');
  ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;
END;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE proc(call_proc3 BOOLEAN, raise_exception BOOLEAN := FALSE)
IS
BEGIN
  childproc1();
  childproc2();
  IF call_proc3 THEN
    childproc3(raise_exception);
  END IF;
END;
/

If you call the procedure so that it calls childproc3:
BEGIN
  proc(call_proc3 => TRUE);
END;
/

Then the result is:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a;




COUNT(*)




0



SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b;




COUNT(*)




0



Note: You get a similar result if childproc3 raises an exception.

If you call the procedure so that it does not call childproc3:
BEGIN
  proc(call_proc3 => FALSE);
END;
/

Then the output is:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a;




COUNT(*)




360



SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b;




COUNT(*)




0



fiddle

Thanks @MT0.  Turns out there was an error in call_proc3.  2 things. Why wouldnt you see an error by default and I commited the other transaction, yet both tables didnt have records.  It rollback the 1st table  insert

@H20rider If the error is uncaught then you will see it - you can see an example of an exception being raised in the linked fiddle and it does show the exception (and stack trace). Without seeing your code (which you have not shared) it is difficult to comment on why you are not seeing the exception (or what you are/aren't committing).

That is what I expected. But I saw 0 errors and the other transactions were rolled back.
